# Python - http.client.HTTPSConnection - ashx return empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, http.client

Can someone please help with http.client.HTTPSConnection please?

I completly did not understand why response return : b''

If i use connection.request('GET', url='/') page returns correctly

```
import http.client
connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection('finviz.com',timeout=30000)
connection.request('GET', url='/screener.ashx')
response = connection.getresponse().read()
print (response)
```